# Deploy flutter to web hosting

Tags: flutter, ftp, filezilla

I try to deploy my first website from Flutter to a web hosting (OVH).
I must build for web, what I did and flutter generated some files and folders in a new web folder. It seems that it is the content of that folder that I have to upload to the host.
Problem is that, no matter if I use FileZilla or the webFTP app of OVH, when I have to select the files to be uploaded, some files (that I see in the Finder) are not shown in/by FileZilla. It is the case of the .js files and of 2 folders.
Hereunder the content as seen in the Finder:
[image]

And here what I see in FileZilla
[image]

Could you explain what I do wrong, how to retrieve and upload the 'missing' files and directories?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Bernard

Comment: Check for `build/web` folder in your project folder, it should contain the built web contents. The `web` folder under your project root is used as an input for `flutter build web`.